# How can I build a webapp which uses google calendar api without having to become verified?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

**What I want to build:**

- I want to build a website where users can connect their google calendars (this will use Google Calendar API's)
  and view their calendar events, as well as edit them, and create new ones.

**My problem:**

- In order to do so, google says my app needs to be verified, which can take weeks, and I also need to set up terms of services pages, privacy policy pages
- I also need to supply authorised javascript origins which MUST start with `https`, which of course is a problem during development, since my origin is `http://localhost`
- I also need to set up support emails and homepage link

**Question**

I just want to start building my application without having to set up a whole production-ready website eco system.

Is there anyway I can use these Google Calendar APIs for editing/creating calendar events locally, without having to set up everything mentioned above first?

Answer (score 0):

[Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) can still be used by the developer who created the project on google developer console.

> ### Unverified app screen
>
> The app or script might display an "unverified app" screen before it displays the consent screen. This is based on the specific scopes that your app includes in the request.

You can still work on your app while you are going though the verification process. However that being said i would start that process asap it can take a long time to get verified.

Comment: And by "app" in this case, that encapsulates web sites as well as mobile apps, right?

Comment: @DalmTo "You can still work on your app while you are going through the verification process." - so in order to start any development work which contains a sensitive scope, you must request verification? And while it's in waiting for verification you can test the API? So there is no way at all to test the API with sensitive scope without going through the verification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As far as I am able to tell, all the verification step does is remove the "unverified app" screen. As long as you click Advanced > Go To ... (unsafe), you should be able to create and edit calendar events for that user in your application.

In order to be able to create and edit calendar events, you need to use the most sensitive scope, which is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`. I couldn't figure out how to edit and create calendar events in my web app until I changed my scope from `calendar.events` to `calendar`.

Creating Events: https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events